# distributing div horizontally does not work when divs are stuck

Tags: html, css

Distributing `div`s horizontally evenly doesn't work (at least in chrome and firefox) when these elements are stuck to each other (i.e. no spaces between them)

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/pdelorme/au9ouko0/

HTML :

```
<div class="ul">
<div class="li">Item 1</div>
<div class="li">Item 2</div><div class="li">Item 3</div>
<div class="li">Item 4</div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.ul {
    text-align: justify;
}
.ul > .li {
    display: inline-block;
}
.ul:after {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
.li {
    background-color: hotPink;
    color: #fff;
}
```

The result is the following :

```
=======================================
Item 1       Item 2 Item 3       Item 4
=======================================
```

This works fine excepts when `Item 2` and `Item 3` are stuck together.

What I want is :

```
=======================================
Item 1     Item 2     Item 3     Item 4
=======================================
```

The problem is that, since my HTML is compressed, the spaces between `div`s are automatically removed so I can't distribute them evenly .

```
<div class="ul"><div class="li">Item 1</div><div class="li">Item 2</div><div class="li">Item 3</div><div class="li">Item 4</div></div>
```

becomes :

```
=======================================
Item 1 Item 2 Item 3 Item 4
=======================================
```

Any idea ?

Comment: It s work for me on your jsfiddle, navigator ?

Comment: your fiddle works fine for me in latest chrome and firefox.

Comment: @Banana : i do same error, you have to remove whitespace in html to see bug

Comment: I did edit the fiddle to show clearly the problem. add/remove space between the divs to see the problem (as @Banana says)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the `flexbox` module with elements justified with `space-between`.  This approach doesn't rely on `display: inline-block` so it doesn't matter if the page generated on server-side has been compressed or not.

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/au9ouko0/4/

```
ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

---

Output (border inserted for clarity)

[image]

Flexbox support across browsers: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: Any way to display a separating | between the items ?

Comment: if we keep the flexbox with no extra markup this is an interesting question. I'll try something

Comment: Found it ! using `li { flex: 1 1 auto }`. see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pdelorme/au9ouko0/7/)

Comment: but the first and last element are not aligned with lateral edges.

Comment: Sorry, you must set `li:first-child {flex: 0 1 auto; } li:last-child {flex: 0 0 auto}`. thanks for pushing me in the right direction ;-)